# How to use css to crop parts of an image

Tags: css

I have the following background image

[image]

How would I use only css to make only 3/4ths of the outer ring visible and selectable like so:[image]

I was able to make only a circle **visible and selectable** using

```
a.outer-ring{
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    border-radius:100px;
```

However I couldn't figure out how to remove an inner circle and how to remove 1/4th of the circle (like a pizza slice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wholeheartedly wouldn't recommend it, but http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/QLrJj/1/ (clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/QLrJj/)

EDIT: I got quite into this idea; here's a pretty neat knockout effect http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/QLrJj/8/show/ based on this that I wrote http://csswizardry.com/2011/11/create-a-notched-current-state-nav/

H

Comment: Well to be fair it depends what you're doing with it, but empty elements for stylistic purposes are something of a no-no for me. Feel free to use that code though if it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks man, but when I do `.ring:hover {cursor:pointer}` It selects the entire circle http://jsfiddle.net/QLrJj/11/, not the outer ring.  Is there any way to make only the outer ring selectable?

Comment: Hmmm… I can't see this being doable as the visual- and actual-boundaries of the ring are two different areas :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Achieve this with pure css. Check this

### http://jsfiddle.net/QLrJj/9/

Comment: I need this to work for a background image so that only the outer ring of the image is selectable.